# Increase the expiry time of cached images of Picasso library

Tags: android, http-headers, picasso

I'm using Picasso Library for image loading in my android app. Picasso library caches images but it has expiry time for cached images. The expiry time was set by the Http headers.

If I want to increase the expiry time how can I achieve that?

or in server side,

How to do it with adding http header and give desired expiry time for the response so that it will have more time.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post code of how did you set http headers?

Comment: @user5155835 I'm unable to do it with http headers. So I used universal image loader instead of Picasso.

Comment: ok, then how did you achieve with UIL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968252/how-to-use-universal-image-loader-offline-caching