# Android Universal Image Downloader - reading all images from the Cache when no network is available

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

I have a listview with images that I populate and  successfully cache the images.These images get  downloaded using the URL I get from the JSON response parsing.I am trying to read all the images from the cache and want to display it in the listview when my app is OFFLINE.How do I do this?

Comment: You can do a bit laborious work make a DB and save your response data and check if device is offline and you have data in db fetch it from db and display it in your adapter

Comment: You can get answer at end of the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968252/how-to-use-universal-image-loader-offline-caching