# ImageView Shared Element Transition between Fragment and Activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, retrofit2, universal-image-loader, shared-element-transition

I am displaying images of movie in a viewpager. Whenever a user selects an image, it would be animated(resized) and drawn on another activity. The problem is I am not able to implement animation correctly.

This is the code of my viewpager(inside **MoviesPager.java** fragment):

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_fragment, container, false);
poster = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.selectedMoviePoster);
final View sharedView=poster;
final String transitionName=y.getOriginalTitle();
ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(),sendMovie, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),sharedView,transitionName).toBundle());
```

Here "y" is the movie object which is going to be displayed.

This is the code of **MainActivity.java** inside which viewpager is implemented:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);//=<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>*/
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Fade());//=<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/fade</item>
getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());//same as above
```

This is the code of **Movie.java** which displays movie details

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Fade());
getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(new ChangeImageTransform());
```

Transition name is set as:

1) in **activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/currentMoviesViewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:transitionName="viewPagerTransition"/>
```

2) in **activity_movie.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorAccent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selectedMoviePoster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

3) in **pager_fragment.xml** which is the xml for fragment of viewpager

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardElevation="40dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selectedMoviePoster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadPosterProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And I am using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup) in both activities to download and display Image.

Also if possible can I store images before loading so that I don'e have to download everytime. Image resize to imageview is also not working perfectly.

I have used two different themes for both activities and here is the code.

4) **styles.xml**:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.FullScreen">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: For caching the downloaded images using Universal  Image Loader take a look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968252/how-to-use-universal-image-loader-offline-caching

Answer (score 0):

What you can do for this transition is :

```
                    View sharedView = holder.event_pic;
                    String transitionName = mContext.getString(R.string.event_image);
                    Intent intent_event_description = new Intent(mContext, EventDescription.class);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                        ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, sharedView, transitionName);
                        mContext.startActivity(intent_event_description, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
                    }
```

> Make sure you provide same id's for both the images.

In your style theme :

```
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

Please provide same transition name to both the images :

```
           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selectedMoviePoster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:transitionName="selectedMoviePoster"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1"/>

            <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/selectedMoviePoster"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:transitionName="selectedMoviePoster"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It worked but I still have problem. First it was showing complete white screen but now it atleast shows animation for activity and image on next screen, but still can't get animation for that poster/image. This is what is happening:https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sfy50p15lbpsdh/20160905-120104.mp4?dl=0.                                       Maybe because another image is being downloaded? What could be solution to this?

Comment: In ActivityCompat.startActivity(getActivity(),sendMovie, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(),sharedView,transitionName).toBundle()); // What is transition name that you are passing ?

Comment: `final String transitionName=y.getOriginalTitle();` in **MoviesPager.java**

Comment: @RushiMThakker See my edit, try to provide same transition names to both the images and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you very much for replying.Second, I tried as you said but the result is that poster is not been displayed on details screen instead white screen is shown. What do you want me to keep as transition name on code side: selectedMoviePoster?

Comment: same transition names in both the images. It should be same as of that you are passing in ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, sharedView, transitionName);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122723/discussion-between-rushi-m-thakker-and-nidhi).