# Multiple Image Save in Android

Tags: android, image, sqlite, android-sdcard, imagedownload

My application uses quite a lot of pictures that are downloaded from the multiple **URLs** and cached locally on the Android phone.Each image have connect to particular Id in SQLite Database . I am wondering, what is the correct way to save those pictures. There are several ways I see.

**Save them on SD Card in a public folder**

**Save them on directly in SQLite Databse**

Please suggest me which is better approach to save these image locally.

Answer (score 1):

Use third party library like releam

Answer (score 0):

I recommend libraries oriented for this common functionality to save lots of work and get the best performance and easy updates. You can choose between [Universal Image Library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), these three are maybe among the best-known between many others. Check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide) or search for differences to know which fit best for your case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks fro reply @Hugo But how to reuse these images when user offline

Comment: These libraries provide options to save images in cache volatile memory and also to "hard saving" images in long term memory. Just select one of them, and take a look at it's documentation or search for the concrete question. I'm sure there are threads talking about it here in SO.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26831674/3214497 to do it with UIL for example, it's the library I use in my projects. And please consider mark the answer as the correct one if so. Remember, this is a help forum. You should also work in your own code and read official documentation. Thanks